# What regulation changes will be implemented in Formula 1 for 2024?

Tags: formula-1

Most years, the FIA implements new rules for Formula 1. In 2024, will there be any new rules or regulations (for example regarding driver safety, engines, race formats, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FIA have already released [the sporting regulations](https://www.fia.com/sites/default/files/fia_2024_formula_1_sporting_regulations_-_issue_1_-_2023-09-26.pdf) and [technical regulations](https://www.fia.com/sites/default/files/fia_2024_formula_1_technical_regulations_-_issue_2_-_2023-08-31.pdf) for 2024, with any changes from the 2023 regulations highlighted in red and pink. There are a whole bunch of them, but most of them are either minor re-wordings, or procedural changes with little to no tangible effect (such as how much running teams are permitted to do during filming events).

There are two main changes worth noting. The first is that teams will only be allowed to use three engines, three MGU-H and MGU-K units, and three turbos per car for the entire season (down from four in 2023). The second is that the cars' roll hoops and wheel tethers will be adjusted, in response to (respectively) Zhou Guanyu's crash at the 2022 British Grand Prix, and a number of incidents in 2023 in which cars have had their wheels torn off in spite of the tethers.

There were initially plans for tyre blankets to be banned in 2024, as a cost-saving measure, but these have been pushed back to 2025 due to concerns about the safety of driving on cold tyres.